# замена символа в строке на другой

Tags: php

как в строке заменить символ стоящий перед точкой ?

пример строк :

```
           $text = "world.png"
           $text2 = "experience1.png"
```

т.е в **$text** нужно заменить d на что-то другое(например букву b),

в **$text2** заменить 1(например заменить на 2)

чтобы получилось

**$text_peredelannoe = "worlb.png"**

**$text2_peredelannoe = "experience2.png"**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так можно

```
$text = "world.png";
$pattern = '/(\w\.)/i';
$replacement = 'b.';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $text);
```

Результат

```
worlb.png
```

Comment: Все надо писать в $replacement